# How to group by in matlab on 2 columns?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

There is a matrix:

W=[1 3 1;1 3 2;1 3 3;1 3 4;3 1 2;3 1 3;2 5 3]

1.I want to group by first two columns, and sum the third column. Ideally the result is

[1 3 10;3 1 5;2 5 3]

2.AND if the first two columns are not in order, how to group by first two columns and sum the third column？ Ideally result is: [1 3 15;2 5 3] or [3 1 15;2 5 3]

Comment: For future questions, please post lines of code rather than images. so it's easier to copy your example values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with [`accumarray`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) and [`unique`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html):

```
x = [1 3 1; 1 3 2; 1 3 3; 1 3 4; 3 1 2; 3 1 3; 2 5 3]; % data
[xu, ~, u] = unique(x(:,[1 2]), 'rows', 'stable');
result = [xu, accumarray(u, x(:,3))];
```

Equivalently, instead of `accumarray` you can use the newer [`splitapply`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html) function:

```
result = [xu, splitapply(@sum, x(:,3), u)];
```

Answer (score 0):

For question2:
If the first and second columns of different rows are the same after swapping, then change the row values to the same.

```
W=[1 3 1;1 3 2;1 3 3;1 3 4;3 1 2;3 1 3;2 5 3];
for i=1:length(W)
    for j=i+1:length(W)
        if W(i,[1,2])==W(j,[2,1])
            W(j,(1:2))=W(i,(1:2));
        end
    end
end
```

Then use `unique` and `accumarray`:

```
[xu, ~, u] = unique(W(:,[1 2]), 'rows', 'stable');
result = [xu, accumarray(u, W(:,3))];
```

result is:`[1 3 15,2 5 3]`

If `W(i,(1:2))=W(j,(1:2));`
result is:`[3 1 15,2 5 3]`

Comment: but is long running time in the case of large datasets, hope you all share a better way